# How can I know the addresses and sizes of all functions (including shared libraries) when the program is running under Linux?

Tags: linux

The program is already loaded into memory. And I need to know all the function addresses and their sizes within the program source code (using tools like nm is OK). All functions mean, to include loaded shared library functions like "printf", and should be the real function address, not the PLT address. How could I implement that?

Comment: Why do you ask? Why do you need the information? What will you do with it?

Comment: I am doing research. So this is probably not so meaningful in engineering.

Comment: Interesting, but which kind of research is motivating your question... (Some of us are researchers, so are probably interested by your motivations).

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure that your question always makes sense, even if [Employed Russian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27055298/841108) gives a practically useful clue.

First, `static` functions in a stripped executable or library (including `static` functions *inside* shared libraries like `libc`) have no visible [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) symbols

Second, some compilers are able (using cloning of functions or other techniques) when optimizing strongly to have function code which is non-contiguous, e.g. because two functions share a piece of common machine code.
In a certain sense, this also happens when the compiler is optimizing [tail-calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call).

And most compilers are able to *inline* function calls (in particular to functions which are not defined as `inline`). With [link-time optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interprocedural_optimization) (e.g. code compiled *and* linked with `gcc -flto -O3`) it may happen even between several translation units.

You could experiment with [dladdr(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dladdr.3.html) & [backtrace(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/backtrace.3.html). You'll find out that function code might have surprising or even poorly defined "boundaries".

Answer (score 1):

> I need to know all the function addresses and their sizes within the program source code
>   (using tools like nm is OK)

You could read `/proc/self/maps` to find out all ELF images currently mapped into your process, and run `nm` on each one.

That will give you all function addresses (for shared libraries, you would need to adjust `nm` output by the relocation (which you also get from `/proc/self/maps`), and most of function sizes.